# How to read USB voltage with my multi-meter?

Tags: multimeter

I am a complete noobie (though built a disco light when I was a teen).  I am trying to read voltage on a USB slot in my PC.  I suspect it's supplying too much of it because it fried 2 USB devices (usb stick and a headset).

Problem is that I don't know which buttons to press on my multi-meter to do what I want and I can't seem to find any tutorial for this super old model on the internet.

[image]

Comment: You're going to find it difficult to measure a USB connector without shorting the power against the grounded shell.  Many hosts are protected against that, but it's not a good practice, and if your host is already suspected of inadequate design you could end up damaging it this way.

Comment: That's quite an old-fashioned multimeter! The meter as you've shown it in the picture should be set up to measure voltage in the appropriate range.

Comment: You would want the selection for 20V DC on that meter, which appears to be what you have selected in that photo.

Comment: It will probably be easier to read the voltages on the PSU connectors than on the tiny little connectors on a USB connector.

Comment: The other way to connect to measure is to take a USB cable, cut off one end and strip the wires. If it has black and red wires, use those. Otherwise, try all the combinations until you find 5 volts or more.

Comment: I would just cut a usb cable to gain access to the USB voltages. But the settings on your meter seems correct. Can you test the meter on a AA or cell phone battery?

Comment: @rohat that's just asking for a short.

Comment: Go buy a usb current meter wherever chinese stuff is sold

Answer (score 1):

On that multimeter, you're going to want to press the 20V switch. USB voltage is constant across all devices: 5 volts. Always. However, if your device is outputting more than 5v, I suggest you take it in. However, it's going to be difficult to measure the voltage, because the outside shell of the USB plug is grounded.